# pyspark: set alias while performing join - restrict same column name selection

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Perform left join. I select columns in the data frame.

```
temp_join=ldt_ffw_course_attendee[["languages_id","course_attendee_status",\
                         "course_attendee_completed_flag","course_video_id","mem_id", "course_id"]].\
join(languages[["languages_id"]],\
     ldt_ffw_course_attendee.languages_id==languages.languages_id,"left")
```

Print columns that get stored in the `temp_join`

```
for col in temp_join.dtypes:
    print(col[0]+" , "+col[1])
```

> languages_id , int course_attendee_status , int
> course_attendee_completed_flag , int course_video_id , int mem_id ,
> int course_id , int languages_id , int

How do I make an alias for `languages_id` in any of the data frame? Or, how do I restrict to select `languages_id` from one data frame only

Comment: `df1.join(df2, ['key_col'], 'left')` -- if all your keys are of same name in both the dataframes, you can pass the names as a list.

Comment: Hi, do you mind sharing/showing the code? I don't understand `list`.

Comment: see example in my earlier comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.alias()` to name your dataframe

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 'b')], schema=['col1', 'col2'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 'c')], schema=['col1', 'col2'])
df3 = df1.alias('df1').join(df2.alias('df2'), on='col1', how='inner')

df3.printSchema()
df3.show(1, False)
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col2|
+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+
```

When you do the query, you can query the column by `df.column_name`:

```
df3.select(
    'df1.col1',
    'df1.col2',
    'df2.col2'
).show(3, False)
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col2|
+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |
+----+----+----+
```